# How to Avoid dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I get some help, I am trying to avoid dynamic sql, the dynamic sql works but its there any other way to build this without dynamic sql, I am trying a lot of stuff but getting errors, your help will be appreciated.

```
declare @strSQL varchar(8000)

set @strSQL = 'Select 
ParentFName, ParentLName, ParentMiddleName, 
MailingAddressLine1, MailingAddressLine2, City, State, ZipCode,  
PS.SchoolID, PS.SchoolName, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, 
CONVERT(varchar(12), SE.Birthday, 101) AS [Birthday], 
SE.GTID, SystemID,Grade, Report_Type, Race, Sex, NON_Funded_Flag, 
DATEDIFF(YY,Birthday , getdate()) -
CASE
WHEN(
  (MONTH(BirthDay)*100 + DAY(BirthDay)) >
  (MONTH(getdate())*100 + DAY(getdate()))
) THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS Age,
KG, GR01_03, GR04_05, GR06_08_Middle_Grade, GR06_08_middle_school, 
GR09_12, EIP_KG, EIP_01_03,EIP_04_05,LEVEL_1,LEVEL_2,LEVEL_3,LEVEL_4,LEVEL_5,GIFTED, REMEDIAL,VOCATIONAL_HS_LAB, SED, --STUDY_HALL, 
NON_FUNDED, --POST_SECOND_OPTION,
ESOL_ITINERANT, ESOL_NON_ITINERANT, TOTAL_ESOL_SEGMENTS,
FiscalYear, TOTAL_FTE_SEGMENTS, AnnualTuition, 
CONVERT(varchar(12), SE.EnrollmentDate,101) AS [Enrollment Date], 
CONVERT(varchar(12), SE.WithdrawalDate,101) AS [Withdrawal Date],
WD.LookupValueDescription as WithdrawalReason,
FREE_REDUCED_LUNCH, PRIMARY_AREA, GNET_FLAG, 
EstAwardAmount--, previous_year
From 
StudentEnrollment SE 
    inner join (
        select * from openquery([FINANCE], ''select * from scholarship.sp_eligible_students Where Fiscal_Year = ''''' + convert(varchar, @FiscalYear) + ''''' '') ) ES ON
        SE.GTID = ES.GTID Inner Join 
        (select FP.FiscalYear, PrivateSchool.* from PrivateSchool
            INNER JOIN FiscalYearPrivateSchool FP ON PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID = FP.PrivateSchoolID AND FP.FiscalYear = ' + @FiscalYear + ') PS 
        ON SE.PrivateSchoolID = PS.PrivateSchoolID AND ES.Fiscal_Year =  PS.FiscalYear Left outer Join 
        vLookUps WD ON SE.WithdrawalreasonId = WD.LookUpID
    WHERE SE.isActive = 1 AND PS.isactive = 1
    AND (' + @SchoolID + ' = -1 or SchoolID = ' + @SchoolID + ' )
    AND (' + @FiscalYear + ' = -1 OR FiscalYear = ' + @FiscalYear + ')
ORDER BY SchoolName, LastName, Firstname, GTID'
--print (@strSQL)
exec (@strSQL)
END
```

Comment: I didnt build it, some one did and I was asked to work on it but I am trying to avoid dynamic sql

Comment: I would write everything from scratch.

Comment: Honestly starting again might be a nicer option for you here. Though maybe look at the table structure too, im not sure what ESOL_ITINERANT and ESOL_NON_ITINERANT are but if im guessing right you cant be both at once, thus you only really need one column here? Same with Gifted and Remedial?  I'll try look through the code some more and suggest how you could do this better but a fresh start would probably be nicer than fixing this

Comment: Alright thanks, I am going to try and start fresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @oq varchar(200)

set @og = 'select * from scholarship.sp_eligible_students Where Fiscal_Year ='+ convert(varchar, @FiscalYear)

select * into #a from openquery([FINANCE], @oq) 

Select  
ParentFName, ParentLName, ParentMiddleName,  
MailingAddressLine1, MailingAddressLine2, City, State, ZipCode,   
PS.SchoolID, PS.SchoolName, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName,  
CONVERT(varchar(12), SE.Birthday, 101) AS [Birthday],  
SE.GTID, SystemID,Grade, Report_Type, Race, Sex, NON_Funded_Flag,  
DATEDIFF(YY,Birthday , getdate()) - 
CASE 
WHEN( 
  (MONTH(BirthDay)*100 + DAY(BirthDay)) > 
  (MONTH(getdate())*100 + DAY(getdate())) 
) THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END AS Age, 
KG, GR01_03, GR04_05, GR06_08_Middle_Grade, GR06_08_middle_school,  
GR09_12, EIP_KG, EIP_01_03,EIP_04_05,LEVEL_1,LEVEL_2,LEVEL_3,LEVEL_4,LEVEL_5,GIFTED, REMEDIAL,VOCATIONAL_HS_LAB, SED,  
NON_FUNDED, 
ESOL_ITINERANT, ESOL_NON_ITINERANT, TOTAL_ESOL_SEGMENTS, 
FiscalYear, TOTAL_FTE_SEGMENTS, AnnualTuition,  
CONVERT(varchar(12), SE.EnrollmentDate,101) AS [Enrollment Date],  
CONVERT(varchar(12), SE.WithdrawalDate,101) AS [Withdrawal Date], 
WD.LookupValueDescription as WithdrawalReason, 
FREE_REDUCED_LUNCH, PRIMARY_AREA, GNET_FLAG,  
EstAwardAmount 
From  
StudentEnrollment SE  
    inner join #a ES ON 
        SE.GTID = ES.GTID Inner Join  
        (select FP.FiscalYear, PrivateSchool.* from PrivateSchool 
            INNER JOIN FiscalYearPrivateSchool FP ON PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID = FP.PrivateSchoolID AND FP.FiscalYear = @FiscalYear) PS  
        ON SE.PrivateSchoolID = PS.PrivateSchoolID AND ES.Fiscal_Year =  PS.FiscalYear Left outer Join  
        vLookUps WD ON SE.WithdrawalreasonId = WD.LookUpID 
    WHERE SE.isActive = 1 AND PS.isactive = 1 
    AND (@SchoolID = -1 or SchoolID = @SchoolID ) 
    AND (@FiscalYear = -1 OR FiscalYear = @FiscalYear) 
ORDER BY SchoolName, LastName, Firstname, GTID

drop table #a
```

If and when this fails. Try fixing it.